# nodejs equivalent of https curl -k request

Tags: node.js, curl

I was following the guide here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html for accessing elasticsearch via a curl request and was wondering how I can translate this `curl -u "elastic:somepassword" -k "https://quickstart-es-http:9200"`  to nodejs.

I have this setup but I'm unable to connect:

```
  https.get(
    "https://quickstart-es-http:9200",
    { headers: { authorization: "Basic elastic:" + process.env.ES_SECRET } },
    (innerRes) => {
      let data = "";
      innerRes.on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("erro>>", err);
      });
      innerRes.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      innerRes.on("end", () => {
        console.log("data", data);
        res.send(data);
      });
      innerRes.on("close", () => {
        console.log("data", data);
        res.send(data);
      });
    }
  );
```

the error message I'm getting is:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.28.9.116:9200
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1133:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.28.9.116',
  port: 9200
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend the [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) library or any of the libraries in [this list](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  Way, way simpler than using the `https` library in this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you recommend how to use got or any of the other libraries to get the equivalent of curl -k...?  That's my main question. I'm pretty open to using any library and I just included my implementation to help get the ball rolling.

Comment: I know the `got()` library, but I don't know curl so your curl spec doesn't mean anything to me.  If you described what kind of request you're trying to send, then perhaps I could help further.  Also, what exact error are you getting?  "unable to connect" is not a very specific description of what the problem is.  Are you getting an https error, a can't connect to host error, an authorization error, an application error, some other error?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks! that's a really good question. In my haste, I left out the error message. I just updated the post with it. It was a ECONNREFUSED error

Answer (score 0):

You can set `rejectUnauthorized` to `false`. See more here https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback

```js
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```